# Way to open Pre-chat form window in the centre of the parent browser screen

Tags: liveagent

when the Agents are online and visitor clicks to engage an agent. If pre-chat form is configured, then it has the tendency to launch on top-left corner of the browser window.

I am trying to explore an option to open the pre-chat window in center of the browser window. i tried with both CSS/html as well as js, in the pre-chat form itself to no avail.

did anyone implement something like this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official support to position the chat form in the Deployment API. Only available setting  is to set the width and height by these API methods `setChatWindowWidth` and `setChatWindowHeight`.

To change the position of the chat window you have to override the `window.open` call present in `deployment.js` to pass left and top position.

Firstly, I made a copy of `window.open()` function in a variable. Then I override the `window.open()` function to pass the additional parameters `top` and `left` including `height` and `width`.

For calculating the left and top position I have used `screen.availWidth` and  `screen.availHeight` to get the screen size.

The default and final code is provided as below.

**Default Deployment Code**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la2w1.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/36.0/deployment.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    /* Sets the width of the chat window */
    liveagent.setChatWindowWidth(377);

    /* Sets the height of the chat window */
    liveagent.setChatWindowHeight(468);

    <!-- Live Agent Deployment Code to initialize, replace with your org's values -->
    liveagent.init('https://d.la2w1.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572i00000006rlJ', '00Di0000000inoh');
</script>
```

**Updated Deployment Code with overridden window.open method**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    liveagent.init('https://d.la2w1.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572i00000006rlJ', '00Di0000000inoh');

    var orgOpen = window.open;
    window.open = function (url, windowName, windowFeatures) {

        /* Width of the chat window. Use your own value. */
        var chatWindowHeight=468;

        /* Height of the chat window. Use your own value. */
        var chatWindowWidth=377;

        /* Calculate the left position to keep the chatwindow in center */ 
        var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth/2) - (chatWindowWidth/2));

        /* Calculate the top position to keep the chatwindow in center */
        var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight/2) - (chatWindowHeight/2));

        /* Create the arguments for window.open method. */
        var windowFeatures = "width=" + chatWindowWidth + ",height=" + chatWindowHeight + ",status,resizable,left=" + left + ",top=" + top + "screenX=" + left + ",screenY=" + top;

        return orgOpen(url, windowName, windowFeatures); 
    }   
</script>
```

*Chat window appears at center of the Screen*

[image]

Comment: Saroj: thanks for the quick response, greatly appreciate it.